# C++ Boost Link error

Tags: c++, boost

I am working on Windows 10 and I downloaded Boost 1.60 for Visual Studio 2015.

My first code snippet looks as:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World";

}
```

I get the error:

```
>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.lib'
```

I have provided path for boost and also libraries as shown in pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded the precompiled libraries for Windows? Meaning, do you actually have the file that's being requested?

Comment: I downloaded boost from boost page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.60.0/

Comment: did you compile the library? after downloading and extracting the package?

Comment: I was under impression that I only need to provide the path

Comment: [Here](http://boost.teeks99.com/) you can find a lot of pre compiled binaries if you don't want to compile them yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile the library before using it. Here's how to compile it:

In your Windows Start menu open the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015". Then inside the opened command prompt, execute those commands:

`cd C:\boost_1_60_0`

`bootstrap.bat`

`.\b2 runtime-link=shared toolset=msvc-14.0`

Wait for a couple of minutes, since compilation takes a while.

Specify in your project in **Linker -> General**, the `Additional Library Directories` path as `C:\boost_1_60_0\stage\lib`, and in **C++ -> General** the `Additional Include Directories` path as `C:\boost_1_60_0`

You should now be able to compile your code without problem.